# Java function returning zero as a result

Tags: java

First off sorry about the title I could not think how I should title this.  The prompt of the assignment had us calculate the volume and surface area of a pyramid and prism with three different classes(two classes with constructors and one test class), and as the title states I keep getting zero.

Here is the prism class:

```
public class Prism
{
double l;
double w;
double h;
public Prism(double intL, double intW, double intH)
 {
     double l = intL;
     double w = intW;
     double h = intH;
 }
 public double getPrismVolume()
 {
     return l*w*h;
 }    
 public double getPrismSurfaceArea()
 {
     return 2*((l*w)+(h*l)+(h*w));
 }    
}
```

Here is my Pyramid class:

```
public class Pyramid
{
    double b;
    double h;
    public Pyramid(double intB, double intH)
    {
       double b = intB;
       double h = intH;
    } 
    public double getPyramidVolume()
    {
       return (1.0/3.0)*Math.pow(b,2)*h;
    }   
    public double getPyramidSurfaceArea()
    {
        return Math.pow(b,2)+(2*b*h);
    }    
}
```

Here is my test class:

```
import java.util.*;
public class GeometryTest
{
 public static void main(String[] args)
    {
    Scanner myScanner = new Scanner(System.in);           
    System.out.print("Enter the length of the prism: ");
    String answer1 = myScanner.nextLine();
    double length = Double.parseDouble(answer1);
    System.out.print("Enter the width of the prism: ");
    String answer2 = myScanner.nextLine();
    double width = Double.parseDouble(answer2);
    System.out.print("Enter the height of the prism: ");
    String answer3 = myScanner.nextLine();
    double height = Double.parseDouble(answer3);
    System.out.print("Enter the pyramid's base: ");
    String answer4 = myScanner.nextLine();
    double base = Double.parseDouble(answer4);
    System.out.print("Enter the pyramid's height: ");
    String answer5 = myScanner.nextLine();
    double pyramidHeight = Double.parseDouble(answer5);
    Pyramid aPyramid = new Pyramid(base,pyramidHeight);
    Prism aPrism = new Prism(length,width,height);
    System.out.println("The prism's volume is: " + aPrism.getPrismVolume());
    System.out.println("The prism's surface area is: " + aPrism.getPrismSurfaceArea());
    System.out.println("The pyramid's volume is: " + aPyramid.getPyramidVolume());
    System.out.println("The pyramid's surface area is: " +  aPyramid.getPyramidSurfaceArea());
    }
}
```

Comment: An important aproach is to reduce the problem. In this cases like this, I recomend yo to, for excample test the method that calculate the volume only. You can do this hardcoding double values for you parameters l,w,h...

Comment: This question would be so much more useful if you were to reduce it down to a class containing a single variable, set that in the constructor, call the constructor from `main` and try to print the value afterwards, and ask why it doesn't change.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your constructors are declaring local variables and ignoring the instance variables.  The instance variables are left uninitialized, so Java initializes them to their default value, `0`.

E.g. change

```
double l = intL;
```

to

```
l = intL;
```

so `l` will resolve to the instance variable name.

Answer (score 1):

You are [hiding](http://www.xyzws.com/Javafaq/what-is-variable-hiding-and-shadowing/15) your class level fields with [variable shadows](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing);

```
public Prism(double intL, double intW, double intH)
{
  // double l = intL;
  // double w = intW;
  // double h = intH;
  this.l = intL;
  this.w = intW;
  this.h = intH;
}
```

and the same problem in Pyramid -

```
public Pyramid(double intB, double intH)
{
   // double b = intB;
   // double h = intH;
   this.b = intB;
   this.h = intH;
}
```